# How to use Symfony Serializer on a nested object with multiple instances of child?

Tags: symfony, serialization

Using the simple example below, how do I update it to handle multiple contact numbers?

```
<?php
/**
* Symfony Serializer experiment  
*/
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libraries/symfony/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;

class Contact
{
    private $name;
    private $number;

    // Getters
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }    
    // Setters
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }    
} 

$data = <<<EOF
<contact>
    <name>foo</name>
    <number>02378415326</number>        
</contact>
EOF;

// The default Root tag for the XmlEncode is <response>. Not what we want so let's change it to <Contact>
$xmlEncoder = new XmlEncoder();
$xmlEncoder->setRootNodeName('Contact');                

$encoders = array($xmlEncoder, new JsonEncoder());

$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer());

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

//$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($searchId, 'json');

$contact = $serializer->deserialize($data, Contact::class, 'xml');

$xmlContent = $serializer->serialize($contact, 'xml');

echo "<pre lang=xml>";
echo htmlentities($xmlContent);
echo "</pre>";     
?>
```

What I would like to know is how to code my classes to be able to serialize/deserialize to/from the following xml, where there can be an arbitrary amount of numbers.?

```
$data = <<<EOF
<contact>
    <name>foo</name>
    <numbers>
        <number>02378415326</number>
        ...
    </numbers>        
</contact>
EOF;
```

I'm guessing I'd start by changing property Number in class Contact to Numbers and making it an array of type Number? Do I need a separate Class for Numbers and Number. Since Numbers is a collection, how do I implement it in a way that I can create Number objects to then add to either a Numbers class, and then to Contacts, or directly to Numbers in Contact in such a way that serialize/deserialize can handle natively? I read that Serialize can understand adders, removers and issers as well as setters and getters but found no examples of how to user adders which looked like it might be useful in my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By experimentation I found this works:

```
<?php
/**
* Symfony Serializer experiment  
*/
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libraries/symfony/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;

Class Number {
    private $Number;
    // Getters    
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->Number;
    }
    // Setters    
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->Number = $number;

        return $this;
    }          
} 

class Contact
{
    private $Name;
    private $Numbers;

    // Getters
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }
    public function getNumbers()
    {
        return $this->Numbers;
    }  
    // Setters
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->Name = $name;

        return $this;        
    }
    public function setNumbers($numbers)
    {
        $this->Numbers = $numbers;

        return $this;        
    }
    public function addNumber($number) {
        $this->Numbers['Number'][] = $number;
    }    
}

$data = <<<EOF
<Contact>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Numbers>
        <Number>02378415326</Number>
        <Number>07865412354</Number>        
    </Numbers>        
</Contact>
EOF;

// The default Root tag for the XmlEncode is <response>. Not what we want so let's change it to <Contact>
$xmlEncoder = new XmlEncoder();
$xmlEncoder->setRootNodeName('Contact');                

$encoders = array($xmlEncoder, new JsonEncoder());

$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer());

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

//$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($searchId, 'json');

$contact = $serializer->deserialize($data, Contact::class, 'xml');

$contact->addNumber('01234567890');

$xmlContent = $serializer->serialize($contact, 'xml');

echo "<pre lang=xml>";
echo htmlentities($xmlContent);
echo "</pre>";     
?>
```

After running deserialization on the xml (xml->php), the Contact object I got was able to add a further Number.

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Contact>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Numbers>
        <Number>02378415326</Number>
        <Number>07865412354</Number>
        <Number>01234567890</Number>
    </Numbers>
</Contact>
```

It works in both directions using no additional directives.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple contact numbers, you need to have separate Number entity. Create new number entity with Id and Number fields and then have a one-to-many relationship of Contact with Number entity.

Then serializer would work correctly to have multiple numbers listed.

```
// Contact.orm.xml

<one-to-many field="numbers" target-entity="Number" mapped-by="number" index-by="NumberId"/>


// Contact.php

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
protected $numbers;

public function __construct()
{    
   $this->numbers= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addNumber(Number $numbers)
{
    $this->numbers[] = $numbers;

    return $this;
}

public function getNumbers()
{
    return $this->numbers;
}
```